# OnResume() causing infinite loop in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I've recently added the OnResume method to my main activity, however, after doing this, my app is now stuck in an infinite loop because OnResume is being called repeatedly, but I don't know why.

Any ideas what it is about my MainActivity code that's causing the OnResume method to be called repeatedly? Or is there a way in Android Studio I can trace back to see where the call originates from?

For reference, the reason I want to call recreate in the OnResume method is that the user can change the active theme in another activity, so when I come back to MainActivity I want it to pick up the theme change.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    static int errorDelay = 2000;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    TabItem tabAveSpeed;
    TabItem tabDistance;
    TabItem tabTime;



    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            View v = getCurrentFocus();
            if (v instanceof EditText) {
                Rect outRect = new Rect();
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
                if (!outRect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
                    v.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (!PrefUtil.getBool(this, "usedBefore")) {
            PrefUtil.saveInt(this, "distanceSpinnerPref", 0);
            PrefUtil.saveBool(this, "usedBefore", true);
            PrefUtil.saveString(this, "activeThemeColour", "Grey");
        }

        String colour = PrefUtil.getString(this, "activeThemeColour");

        switch (colour) {
            case "Green":
                setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Green);
                break;
            case "Grey":
                setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Grey);
                break;
            default:
                setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Grey);
                break;
        }


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabMenu);
        tabAveSpeed = findViewById(R.id.averageSpeedTab);
        tabDistance = findViewById(R.id.distanceTab);
        tabTime = findViewById(R.id.timeTab);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));



        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        recreate();
    }

    public void updateTabTitle (String newTitle){
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabMenu);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(newTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does recreate() do?

Comment: @Blundell - here's the documentation for it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()
I'm following the tutorial from here: https://medium.com/@vinitagrawal91/android-colors-and-multiple-themes-fdfca3f75a15
From my basic understanding, in essence it just destroys the activity and creates it again. I my case I want to do this so it pulls through the new theme on creation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, indiscriminately calling `recreate()` in your `onResume()` method is going to give you infinite loops.

You can probably do something like write a value to `SharedPreferences` whenever the user changes the theme, and then check that value in your `onResume()` and only call `recreate()` if the theme has changed.

In your other activity, when the user changes the theme, do this:

```
PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        .edit()
        .putBoolean("theme_changed", true)
        .apply();
```

And then in your other activity, inside `onResume()`, do this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

if (prefs.getBoolean("theme_changed", false)) {
    prefs.edit().remove("theme_changed").apply();
    recreate();
}
```

In this way, you'll only `recreate()` when there's a reason to do so, and won't loop forever.

Comment: Thanks Ben. That's working nicely now and I'm not stuck in a loop any more, but I still don't understand why the OnResume method was repeatedly called. From the lifecycle diagram here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle, it says that another activity would need to come to the foreground, and then return back to the original activity in order for OnResume() to be called. Where in my MainActivity is this other activity starting?  There's only one other activity in the project, but that's not started unless the user selects the settings button on the menu

Comment: When your activity starts up (any activity), it will call `onCreate()`, then `onStart()`, and then `onResume()`. What that diagram is trying to say is that if you start a new activity and then return to the first one, you will get _another_ set of calls to `onStart()` and `onResume()`. But since you _always_ get create->start->resume for an activity starting up for the first time, calling `recreate()` from any of these methods will give you an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `recreate();` from this line:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //recreate();  - delete this line
}
```

You can read [here in docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) what `recreate()` do.

Comment: Granted, removing that line fixes the infinite loop, but I want to call recreate() in order to essentially redraw everything and display the new theme.

Comment: But you want to redraw everything on the start of activity? I think that dosen't have sence.